# Timestamp resolution

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, precision

I need to set as primary key a timestamp type,(in each case it must be unique, some instructions could insert k records at time) with default value "current_timestamp". It is a kind of log file. To do this I should improve the timestamp resolution to microsecs(I do not think is possible for pg write a million of records in a sec). This kind of precision is possible for postgres.[See here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html) It is something like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE upsistema
(
  t timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(6) without time zone,
  blabla bigint,
  foo bigint,
  CONSTRAINT "XIDS3w" PRIMARY KEY (t)
)
```

But it does not work. When I check, with pgAdmin3, it writes ever with millisecs precision.
And of course , it is possible write more records in the same millisecond.
So, did I need to set some misterious variable or something else, in order to save with microsecs precision?

Comment: hmmm, I've tested it and it works fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/619a0/1

Comment: _I do not think is possible for pg write a million of records in a sec_: you're kidding yourself. My ubuntu desktop box with a cheap Intel i5 CPU imports 1 million rows into a temp table in less than 0.4s

Comment: Are you sure? If your record as 20 bytes (it is enough three fields), it means it should write 20 MBytes in a second, in the Hard Disk. So IDK. I tried a simple loop:  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE t timestamp;
declare i bigint;
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..1000000 LOOP
insert into tst values(i);
    -- i will take on the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 within the loop
END LOOP;
 
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;  It needs 27 secs. The table tst, has just a field. I think the limit is the hard disk not the processor or the OS. Soooo... IDK

Comment: I meant this: `CREATE TABLE t(id int); INSERT INTO t select * from generate_series(1,1000000);` **Time: 733,429 ms** including the commit to a HDD (not even a SSD).

Answer (score 13):

By default, PostgreSQL stores timestamps at the maximum possible precision.

If I were in your shoes, I might use a different default for the timestamp. The value of current_timestamp is the time the current transaction started. It doesn't change during execution of a transaction, no matter how many rows you insert, and no matter how long it takes. That means INSERT statements are liable to fail because of duplicate primary key values.

```
create table upsistema (
  t timestamp without time zone primary key
    default current_timestamp,
  foo bigint
);
insert into upsistema (foo) values (42), (43), (44);
```

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "upsistema_pkey"
```

Try clock_timestamp() as the default instead. This doesn't guarantee success, but it does make it more likely.

```
create table upsistema (
  t timestamp without time zone primary key
    default clock_timestamp(),
  foo bigint
);
insert into upsistema (foo) values (42), (43), (44);

select * from upsistema;
```

```
t                              foo
--
2014-11-19 19:17:23.369432     42
2014-11-19 19:17:23.36958      43
2014-11-19 19:17:23.369587     44
```

To absolutely guarantee success, either change the primary key constraint, or drop it altogether. Whether this makes sense is application-dependent, but I would *not* be surprised to find multiple clients logging data at the same microsecond.

Your table uses `timestamp without time zone`, but current_timestamp and clock_timestamp() return `timestamp with time zone`. It might be a good idea to change the time zone to UTC for your session before you run SQL statements.

```
set time zone 'UTC';
select ... ;
```

and

```
set time zone 'UTC';
insert ... ;
```

If it makes sense to set the *server* to use UTC by default, you can set the timezone parameter in postgresql.conf to 'UTC'. Then you don't have to set the time zone in each session.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After a long research, I found this post: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9699.1262011789@sss.pgh.pa.us The problem is in Windows... I must implement a serial

Comment: Good find. PostgreSQL relies on the underlying operating system for a lot of things.

Comment: From where did you take that "PostgreSQL stores timestamps at the maximum possible precision"? Couldn't find that in the docs.

Comment: @Markus: I have no idea where I learned that. I might have learned that by inspection. On my desktop, `select current_timestamp;` returns fractional seconds as '2020-10-20 06:44:38.179436'. Six digits for fractional seconds is currently the maximum precision for a timestamp. (It hasn't always been that way; IIRC it varied in much earlier PostgreSQL versions.)

Answer (score 3):

As you saw it in the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html), the resolution can be up to `microseconds` using the `timestamp` type.

Here is an example that show you that microseconds are there:

```
CREATE TABLE table_test
(
  column1 timestamp(6) without time zone,
  column2 timestamp(6) without time zone
);

insert into table_test (column1,column2) values (current_timestamp, current_timestamp + interval '100 MICROSECONDS');

select  extract (MICROSECONDS  from column1 - column2 ) from table_test;
```

Result:

```
date_part
-----------
      -100
(1 ligne)
```